# App slow down when I click on options menu

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, progress-bar, android-menu

I am working on and Android app, the main page has map fragment and some animations, when I click on options menu everything gets slow and paused for a second before the menu show up, and when I select an item from the menu same thing happens for a second until changes committed. 
I use the menu to change Map type (standard, Satellite, Terrain)
Can I add a loading or progress bar before and after calling the menu options method everytime onOptionsItemSelected?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.first:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.second:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
1. Remove MapStyleOptions styleOptions;
2. Clear map before changing type

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //Add menu handling code
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.first:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.second:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I have few map styles in JSON in additional to the map types, but I tried it anyways and it didn't work

Comment: whats your code on onResume(). Try adding mMap.onResume() on onResume() of activity.